# Amplifier for 100kHz magnetostrictive ultrasound emitter

Tags: amplifier, ultrasound, class-b-amplifier

I need an amplifier to drive an ultrasound emitter (inductive load, 120uH, 0.3 ohm). Single supply circuit would be preferable. Bandwidth - from 40 to 200kHz, output power 6-10W at 4 ohm load. The input signal is sine wave.

I tried TDA2050, but at ~15kHz it's output current starts to drop and at 100kHz it's only 80 mA. Also I found [this](http://www.redcircuits.com/Page164.htm) circuit, but when I try to simulate it in Multisim, I get nothing at the output with ±12V supply.

Comment: See if any of thesde circuits will give you ideas  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=ultrasonic+transducer+driver+circuit&tbm=isch

Comment: But why asking specifically for sine wave drive? At such high frequency, the inductance of the load should form low pass filter to square wave signal and at the end the emitted ultrasound will be not much different if compared to pure sine drive....or it will?

Comment: No, that's not what I need, there's only circuits for piezoelectric transducers, not magnetostrictive. As for square wave, good idea, I'll try it